# C# Regex between html tags

Tags: c#, html, regex, text, between

Heres the original input: `<div class="title">Name Name<br/>Score: 24375</div>`

Heres my regex: `@"<div.*?class=""title"".*?>(?<div>).*</div>"`

This is what I got from the site: `<div class="title">Name Name<br/>Score: 975</div>`

I would like to get the `Name Name` from the tags.

Comment: [You can't parse HTML with regex](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2596334).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a lookbehind to match the content of `<div>` tag until a `<` or `>` symbol is reached.

```
(?<=<div\s*class=""title""[^><]*>\s*)[^<>]*
```

[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/GCJ3Ng)